# Loading library rpy2/R

Tags: rpy2

I had this message:

> ImportError: dlopen(/Users/u0116155/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libintl.9.dylib
>
> Referenced from: /Users/u0116155/anaconda/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
> Reason: image not found

I tried several things like reinstalling `rpy2` but it still does not work.
Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: What OS are you using? OSX?

Comment: It is macOS Sierra Version 10.12.5

Comment: Are you using Python3.x or Python2.7. ow did you install rpy? Looks like you are using Anaconda? Not too familiar with that but this may require specific installation procedures.

Comment: I'm using Python2.7 and I installed rpy. I am not familiar with Anaconda, I just started to use it. But I have this issue and can not continue...